viewport show the wrong compositing result
I use two view layers to compositing. It's show correct in the compositor window, but when the compositing node connect to the first view layer,
it effect both view layers in the viewport, when the node connect to other view layer, the effect doesn't change anything in the viewport.
Viewport always show incorrect result, did I miss some steps?

Hello, you can't see all the effects in the Viewport, maybe it's your problem here

Could you explain what the problem is? Is there any step or setting that I missed?
